# Varnish + NGINX: Use Wordpress in domain.tld/blog as separate Backend server not in location block

Tags: nginx, wordpress, varnish

I want to serve a wordpress NGINX backend everytime the user visits `www.domain.tld/blog`. I know I can use different backends with Varnish like this:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = wordpress;
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = default;
    }
}
```

I know I could use a separate `location ^~ /blog {}` in NGINX, but this has the following disadvantage: If I use `www.domain.tld/blog` in the wordpress `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` variables some plugins do not work correctly. So I need to deliver wordpress without the trailing `/blog` at the end as a stand alone vhost.

So, what I actually want to achieve is:

```
User -> www.domain.tld/blog (Varnish) -> blog.domain.tld (Wordpress NGINX)
```

The main thing is that the content on `blog.domain.tld/some-post` should be displayed as `www.domain.tld/blog/some-post`. But, `blog.domain.tld` blog should not be accessible publicly as this would mean duplicate content.

So, how could I make `blog.domain.tld/some-post` "resolve" to `www.domain.tld/blog/some-post` with Varnish and NGINX and simultaneously making `blog.domain.tld` not world accessible?

I hope this was understandable :)

P.S.: It's not necessary for me to use `blog.domain.tld` - this is just an example, it could also be a `127.0.0.1:8008` vhost, doesn't matter.

Comment: This is a horribly bad idea. You'll need a lot more than simple Varnish (or even nginx!) tricks to make this "work". You'll probably even have to hack the WordPress core. A lot. Just stick with `blog.example.com`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I agree, using only `blog.example.com` is much easier, but not so SEO friendly as a subdirectory. Either I'll go without some addons or loose some SEO points.

Comment: Who said it wasn't as SEO friendly? I've heard that before, but AFAIK there's actually no significant difference.

Comment: I read not just ones, that Google treats different hostnames as different hosts/sites. So `www.mydomain.tld` will not benefit as much from good SEO posts on `blog.mydomain.tld` as if it was in a subdirectory AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, but they are in the same domain, and that's what counts. It's a lot more important to publish good content.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece in `vcl_recv` will provide what you want by rewriting the URL that the backend will see:

```
if (req.http.host == 'domain.tld' || req.http.host == 'www.domain.tld') {
  set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/blog/", "/");
}
```

However I don’t understand what are those plugins and why they should be tolerated :)